# Read in file and print as a web. 2D array

Tags: java, matrix

Lets say the file has the word "cat." It would have to be printed

`T
  A   A
 C     C
A  A  A  A
T    T   T
A  A   A  A
C       C
A      A
    T`

//I know it doesn't look perfect. Basically it needs to printed as a diamond. This is what I have so far

```
    double x = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    if(s.length() % 2 != 1)
    {
        x = Math.pow(s.length(), 2);
    }
    else
    {
        x = Math.pow(s.length(), 2);
    }

    mat = new char[(int)x][(int)x];

    for(int y = 0; y<mat.length; y++)
    {

    }
```

I have no idea what to do after this. I know I need to set an index to one dimension of an array? Any help is appreciated

Comment: "I know it doesn't look perfect".  I'm not even sure what the pattern is?  If you indent your pattern with 4 spaces (like your code), it will show as you expect.

Comment: @mellamokb It has to be printed as a diamond.

Comment: To generalize this to different word lengths, I think it would be helpful to have a more formal, maybe even a mathematical, description of the problem.